# Как в Windows сделать несколько копий директории и поменять название директорий?

Tags: windows, cmd

Есть такая структура папок:

```
- main
  -ru
    - dir
      - css
      - js
      - index.html
```

Можно ли как-то автоматически средствами Windows (например, через командную строку) автоматически сделать несколько копий папки RU и переименовать название папки? Например, чтобы была такая структура:

```
- main
  - ru
    - внутренние файлы
  - en
    - внутренние файлы (как в ru)
  - kz
    - внутренние файлы (как в ru)
  - au
    - внутренние файлы (как в ru)
  - cz
    - внутренние файлы (как в ru)
  - th
    - внутренние файлы (как в ru)
```

Comment: Тут принято отмечать ответы, которые помогли.

Answer (score 0):

Это можно сделать в Windows множеством способов, например, с помощью

1. интерпретатора командной строки (cmd.exe),
2. PowerShell,
3. VBScript,
4. JScript

Ниже пример на PowerShell

```
$array = "ru","en","kz","au","cz","th"
$from = "c:\test\main\ru"
$to = "c:\test\mail"
foreach ($x in $array)
{
  Copy-Item -Path $from -Destination ($to + "\" + $x) -Recurse
}
```

Answer (score 0):

А вот пример с использованием командной строки. Сначала нужно сделать текстовый файл в папке mail, пусть он будет называться "a.txt". В него поместить страны построчно:

en

kz

и т. д.

А потом из папки mail (открыть папку в Проводнике и напечатать в строке адреса cmd) дать команду

```
for /f %a in (a.txt) do xcopy ru %a /h /i /e
```

Comment: По-моему, это можно сделать и без текстового файла `FOR %a IN (ru, en, kz) DO ...`

Comment: @АлексейР Очень верное дополнение